# XSL - Replace node value from other structure but with the same name

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to replace some nodes value. The idea is searching for the node with the same name in other structure and replace the value.

Here I am changing the values from Body/A with Rule/A and Body/C/D with Rule/D.

Something like this.

```
<Message>
<XMLNSC>
    <MaXML>
        <Rule>
            <A>RuleA</A>
            <D>RuleD</D>
            <E>RuleE</E>
        </Rule>
        <Body>
            <A>valA</A>
            <B>valB</B>
            <C>
                <D>valD</D>
            </C>
        </Body>
    </MaXML>
</XMLNSC>
```

To this.

```
<Message>
<XMLNSC>
    <MaXML>
        <Rule>
            <A>RuleA</A>
            <D>RuleD</D>
            <E>RuleE</E>
        </Rule>
        <Body>
            <A>RuleA</A>
            <B>valB</B>
            <C>
                <D>RuleD</D>
            </C>
        </Body>
    </MaXML>
</XMLNSC>
```

Currently I am looping through all children, searching for the match between nodes' names, but how should I keep the same structure and just change the value?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- copy all -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- match Body -->
<xsl:template match="Body">
    <Body>
        <!-- all children from body -->
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*">
            <xsl:variable name="maNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="nodeName" select="name()"/>
            <!-- all rules -->
            <xsl:for-each select="//Rule/*">
                <xsl:variable name="varRuleName" select="name()"/>  
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- match rule -->
                    <xsl:when test="$nodeName = $varRuleName">
                        <element name="match"/>
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <element name="unmatch"/>
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Body>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach with the identity template

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

is fine, now to use that you just need to add templates for those elements you want to change e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="Body/A">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::MaXML/Rule/A"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTK

It should be clear I hope how to add a third template matching `Body/C/D` and selecting the value from the corresponding `Rule` as needed.

If you need a generic approach then in XSLT 2 or 3 that is easy with a key and a key function call in the subtree:

```
  <xsl:key name="ref" match="MaXML/Rule/*" use="node-name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="Body//*[key('ref', node-name(), ancestor::MaXML)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="key('ref', node-name(), ancestor::MaXML)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Full XSLT 3 at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTK/3 is then

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="ref" match="MaXML/Rule/*" use="node-name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="Body//*[key('ref', node-name(), ancestor::MaXML)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="key('ref', node-name(), ancestor::MaXML)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately XSLT 1 does not have a third argument to the `key` function so there to implement the generic approach with a key you need to include the `generate-id(ancestor::MaXML)` in the key value:

```
  <xsl:key name="ref" match="MaXML/Rule/*" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::MaXML), '|', name())"/>

  <xsl:template match="Body//*[key('ref', concat(generate-id(ancestor::MaXML), '|', name()))]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="key('ref', concat(generate-id(ancestor::MaXML), '|', name()))"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTK/4.

Comment: Another thing, I've just duplicated the matched node by added the same element.
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTK/5

But how can I duplicate the parent instead of the matched child?
Can I set a key for each child's parent match in the template?

This is what I expect to get,
<Body>
 <A>valA</A>
 <B>valB</B>
 <C>
  <D>RuleD</D>
 </C>
 <C>
  <D>RuleD</D>
 </C>
</Body>

Comment: @59parede, I think this warrants a new question with all details of input sample, XSLT you have, result you get and result you want as nicely formatted code samples together with an explanation of the exact conditions to match and copy or duplicate.

Comment: done. Thanks for your help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042099/xsl-duplicate-childs-parent-node